# koushikdutta Ion Frame in Android L have a bug

Tags: android, frame, android-ion

koushikdutta Ion Frame in Android L  have a bug.

eg: when app have many times On/off ,it have let app die

this is Log：

```
 **java.lang.Error java.io.IOEception:File descritor closed
   Caused by:java.io.IOException:File descriptor closed
   at libcore.io.posix.writeByte(Native Method)
   at java nio.SelecorImpl.wakeup
   at com.koushikdutta.async.s.run(Unknow source);**
```

Comment: This is not the right place for filing bug reports.

Comment: I just want to have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Will do a release on maven soon.

https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync/issues/196